# User to change a variable in a compiled macro

Tags: macros, autohotkey

I have a variable with a value stored in an AutoHotKey macro. I want the user to be able to change the variable whenever they want and to have the macro use the new value stored in the variable when the macro is launched in the future. Is it possible to change a variable in a running macro and have the macro use the new variable value the next time the macro is launched? Alternatively, is there a way for the user to change a variable in a compiled macro? I'm also wondering about how to the user interface would be like for the user to be able to change the variable when the user chooses to change the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can store the variable in a text file. This will be the most simple and reliable method to change a variable and store it permanently. 
Here is an example. Create a file "config.txt" in the same directory and put the text there. Pressing `F1` will reload the text file into variable `v`.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

fname := "config.txt"       ; define file name (must be in the same directory)
loadvar(fname)              ; load file
return                      ; end main 

; loadvar function
loadvar(fname){
    global v
    FileRead, v, %fname%
    tooltip %v%
}

; reload variable
F1::
    loadvar(fname)
return
```

Comment: Is there a way to secure the text file? Would it work if the file was encrypted?

Comment: @JimmyWayne This script just reads the file contents and assigns it to variable. It means a user simply edit this file with any  text editor. To read encrypted file you will need a function which decrypts the file. And what sense? if a user can see and edit the text then why you need to hide it in the file?

Comment: Yes, how do you encrypt and decrypt the file?

Comment: @JimmyWayne with AHK I can't recall of a built-in solution, but maybe some libraries. Why not google?. Depends also on level of security I suppose. You could set up some simple cipher inside AHK, e.g. random byte shifting and then compile it so it will be not visible. Anyway its another question and there are different approaches.